# How to force a second instance of a program to open?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-instances

I'm using a piece of Windows software (DS Clock) which, by default, doesn't allow a second instance to be opened. When I double click the executable, nothing happens if the software is already open.

Is there a way I can force a second instance to open up?

Comment: Probably not...

Answer (score 2):

If the program checks that it is the only instance, this is probably
not possible if the program doesn't have such an option.

You could run the first instance in
[Windows Sandbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview),
to isolate it from the second instance, but this is not an easy
solution.

I assume that the problem is showing the time in multiple time zones.
I would suggest in this case to use a multi-zone clock product,
for which there exist many free products.

See for example [this list](https://alternativeto.net/software/qlock/).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the complexity and structure of the program, you might be able to do the following:

Locate the .exe file (right-click on the shortcut -> properties -> target). Duplicate the .exe file and give it a different name. Then execute that second file next to the original one. You'll need administrator priviledges to do that.

If that doesn't work, try to duplicate the whole installation directory, but still renaming the .exe file.

Comment: This is unlikely to work, as the program won't use its executable name as the identifier. The usual method is to check for a window created with the same ID. Changing that window ID in the copied program will require hacking its binary.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Install SandBoxie Plus
2. Open SandBoxie Plus
3. Right Click DefaultBox
4. Run
5. Run Program
6. Add DS Clock.exe Path, OK
7. Right Click DS Clock.exe in SandBoxie
8. Create and Save Shortcut

For Multiple Instances Create New Boxes and repeat process